# Determining $ \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{a}\exp({-x}) dx $

Tags: integration, limits

I know how to calculate the limit of a function and I also know how to integrate but why are the correct steps of working out when the integral is changing e.g.

Determine

$$ \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{a}\exp({-x})dx $$

Any ideas?

Comment: Evaluate $\int_{0}^{a}e^{-x} dx$.  It will be a function of $a$.  Now take the limit of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** To find $\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, you can find $\lim_{a\to\infty}F(a)-F(0)$, where $F$ is the [antiderivative](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi485juisrWAhWELlAKHfaADGkQFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAntiderivative&usg=AFQjCNH1HM2ecQ9UAhysZYyzIxpY6l9x6g) of $f$. In other words, you can find the antiderivative of $e^{-x}$ and then subtract its value at $a\to\infty$ from its value at $0$.

Comment: Well, it is usually called "calculate the integral"...

Comment: @zwim What's your point?

Comment: I just prefer Aaron point of view, than this one which is a bit overcomplicated imho.

Comment: Both answers are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\lim_{a\to \infty} \int_0^a e^{-x}dx = \lim_{a\to \infty} (1-e^{-a}) = 1.$$